# How to get autocomplete suggestions for java programmatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, intellij-plugin

I am trying to build my own java ide and for that I would like to have an autocomplete feature just like the autocomplete on eclipse (ctrl+space).
Is there a service which I can call to get autocomplete data or does eclipse expose it's autocomplete library as a service?

Comment: Press alt+enter

Comment: Eclipse JDT (Java Development Toolkit) is Java only.

Comment: So any solutions??

Comment: The [Visual Studio Code Java extension](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java) is a headless Eclipse as [language server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol).

Comment: @howlger how do i use it, there docs simply refer to it as a vs code extension

Comment: You have to implement a [Language Server Protocol (LSP) client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol) to be able to use any language server. If you code in Java, you can use the [LSP4J](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.lsp4j) library for that.